# Way to split a "xx: xxx yy: yyy" kind of string in php

Tags: php, regex

What would be in PHP the way to split the following string:

```
"dc: http://purl.org/dc/terms/ foaf: http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/"
```

into:

```
"dc: http://purl.org/dc/terms/"
"foaf: http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/"
```

and then add <> to the urls

```
"dc: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>"
"foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>"
```

?

Comment: You'll have to write a program. Give it a try and if you have problems, post them here and perhaps we can help you.

Comment: what you have tried so far..?
Any specific pattern in your string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that would work with any number of tokens:

```
<?php
    $string = 'dc: http://purl.org/dc/terms/ foaf: http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/';

    $explode = explode(' ', $string);
    $lines = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($explode); $i += 2) {
        $lines[] = $explode[$i] . ' <' . $explode[$i + 1] . '>';
    }
    $string = implode("\n", $lines);

    echo $string;
?>
```

Output:

```
dc: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/Kc4gKvNF)

---

Regex solution (replace `/([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) ?/` with `$1 <$2>\n`):

```
<?php
    $string = 'dc: http://purl.org/dc/terms/ foaf: http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/';

    $string = preg_replace('/([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) ?/', "$1 <$2>\n", $string);

    echo $string;
?>
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/64210)

**Regex autopsy:**

- `([^ ]+)` - A capturing group matching any character that is not a space one to infinite times
- `[SPACE]` - A literal space character
- `([^ ]+)` - A capturing group matching any character that is not a space one to infinite times
- `[SPACE]?` - An optional literal space character

Answer (score 4):

I would do

```
$tmp = explode(" ", $string);
echo "{$tmp[0]} <{$tmp[1]}>\n";
echo "{$tmp[2]} <{$tmp[3]}>\n";
```

if you dont know the length of the key/val pairs you can use a loop and know that every 2 items form a key/val pair.

Comment: `$tmp[0]` already contains the colon so you don't need to echo another one.

Comment: Nice answers, but if title is correct - space after colon can be omited

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. Fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work

```
<?php
$str="dc: http://purl.org/dc/terms/ foaf: http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/";
$str=explode("/ ",$str);
$str[0]=str_replace(': ',': <',$str[0]);
$str[1]=str_replace(': ',': <',$str[1]);
echo $str[0]=$str[0].'>'; //dc: <http://purl.org/dc/terms>
echo $str[1]=$str[1].'>'; //foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to make it as easy as possible:

```
$new_string = trim(preg_replace('~([a-z]+:\s)(.*?)(\s|$)~', "[@@@]$1 <$2>", 
              $original_string), "[@@@]");
```

`$original_string` is your input string. Just explode it to get an array.

```
$array = explode("[@@@]", $new_string);
print_r($array);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => dc:  <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
    [1] => foaf:  <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
)
```